# YT iframe API throwing an error when subscribing to events using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I stumbled upon an issue when using YT iframe API.

I have an YT iframe already set-up, and right after it I load the iframe API script:

```
<div class="youtube-wrapper">
  <iframe
    class="youtube"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{youtube_id}}?controls=1"
    frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen
    enablejsapi="true">
  </iframe>
  <script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api" async></script>
</div>
```

I don't need to support older browsers, so I opted to load it like this.

In document head I have this defined:

```
window.onYoutubePlayerStateChange = console.log;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  window.ytPlayers = $('iframe.youtube[enablejsapi]')
    .map(function(youtubeIframe) {
      return new YT.Player(youtubeIframe);
    })
    .get();
  window.ytPlayers.forEach(function(ytPlayer) {
    ytPlayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onYoutubePlayerStateChange')
  })
};
```

This breaks on adding event listener with `Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null`. Looking at where it breaks, it's in www-widgetapi.js:107:7 where in

```
this.f.subscribe(a,c)
```

`this.f` is null.

I also tried adding the event listener only when the API is ready, with

```
var player = new YT.Player(ytIframe, {
  events: {
    'onReady': function(e) { e.target.addEventListener(...); }
  }
});
```

, and I tried adding an `onStateChange` event handler there, but those handlers simply never get called.

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Do you have existing markup that this applies to?

I think you would first need to have an iframe with the enablejsapi attribute on it on your page to get the jquery loop to return good results.

After that, are you sure that you are passing the prope data to your YT.Player instance?

Comment: The documentation for the API shows an itialization argument that looks like this:

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
```

Comment: So it seems like the id of the destination is the first argument, followed by initialization settings.

Comment: I believe that in your code above ytIframe is the iteration index of your each call, and then if you were to pass a second argument, it would be the element in question. So you can get the element id with something like the following

Comment: each(function(i,ele){
  ele.id
}

Comment: I was writing from memory, so mistakenly used jQuery's each. I updated the question by copy/pasting from source files. According to API: The first parameter specifies either the DOM element or the id of the HTML element where the API will insert the <iframe> tag containing the player. I tried with adding enablejsapi=1 to iframe src as well, but it was the same.

Comment: Ok, got it. Sorry, I am a noob trying to be helpful here.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that each iteration of .map returns a valid YT.Player instance?

Comment: That was one of the issues in the end, yes. I assumed the callback signature was same as in native map method, but it's not. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, my pleasure. Glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that contrary to documentation, setting the iframe `enablejsapi="true"` doesn't work, and only when you add `enablejsapi=1` query param to iframe src, player is set-up properly.

(I also didn't help myself by misusing the jQuery.map method which gives index of the element as the first param to the callback)